# WiX: The "ReadRegistry" task could not be loaded from the assembly [...] This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, wix

I've developed an application using Visual Studio 2008 targeted at .NET Framework version 3.5. Now I wanted to create an installer for the application using WiX. I installed the WiX toolkit and then created a WiX project in the same solution as my project. However, I can't even build the empty template created by Visual Studio because of some version dependency problems (it seems).

I'm really new to WiX, so I can only speculate about the reason for this. I've tried re-installing the Framework on my development machine (it's v4, btw), that didn't help.

Full error message:

```
C:\Programme\MSBuild\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\wix200x.targets(499,5): error MSB4062:
The "ReadRegistry" task could not be loaded from the assembly
C:\Programme\MSBuild\..\WiX Toolset v3.7\bin\WixTasks.dll.
Could not load file or assembly
'file:///C:\Programme\WiX Toolset v3.7\bin\WixTasks.dll'
or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the
currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded. Confirm that the <UsingTask>
declaration is correct, and that the assembly and all its dependencies are available.
```

The file paths from the error message are correct btw, all those files exist. From what I get from the message, the dll WiX is trying to load is too new to be used for my installer, which is using an old (framework?) version. The message also points me to a `<UsingTask>` element, however I cannot find such an element anywhere in the relevant files...

thx for any help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a known bug in WiX v3.7 RC, fixed in this week's build v3.7.1126.0.

Comment: still see this in 3.8, any idea?